# ¿Como puedo solucionar Failed to compile cuando uso input(v-model)?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al usar la etiqueta input(v-model="name") me sale que error de compilación

Comment: Por favor coloca tu código, te recomiendo leer [ask]

Comment: Como recomendacion por favor coloca un poco de tu codigo para poder saber en donde esta tu error y en que consiste por favor.

Answer (score 1):

El problema no está con el input, sino que el contenido solo puede contener  un elemento padre, En tu caso sería tan fácil como poner todo el contenido dentro del div padre, el #app

```html
<div id="app">
  <input v-model="name">
</div>
```